# When and How to run pagerank algorithm in neo4j?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher, pagerank, neo4j-apoc

I build a Data model with

**Nodes with labes**: User, Post, Comment, Page, Group

**Relationships**:
FOLLOW(User->User/Page), WRITE(User->Post/Comment), LIKE(User->Post/Comment), AT(between Post and Comment), HAS(between Post and Group), BELONG_TO(User->Group)

**Diagram**: (User)-[FOLLOW]->(User)-[Write]->(Post)<-[AT]-(Comment)<-[WRITE]-(User)-[BELONG_TO]->(Group)-[HAS]->(Post)<-[LIKE]-(User)-[FOLLOW]->(PAGE)-[WRITE]->(Post)

I want to build a api get newsfeed with CYPHER query get Post order using pagerank. I tried with

```
apoc.algo.pageRank()
apoc.algo.pageRankWithConfig()
```

**Question**: Anytime call api get newsfeed (server neo4j become slowly with this query include this algorithm) or get score for Post nodes then save score as property node (build a small graph for a user). How to use pagerank and need call it when?

Answer (score 0):

I think that PageRank algorithm  unsuit for social network. You can search with keyword: edgerank.

Comment: But I don't see edgerank in proc and func. This mean I must build it as a new proc or func.

Comment: Sure. You have to do that.